# python code from batch file failures

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-3.x

When I run this code normally, it executes normally, but when I point my batch file at it (which I've tested on other code to make sure I know how to do it properly) it chooses not to make any of the dirs and the icon. Code is:

```
from sys import argv
import os, winshell
from win32com.client import Dispatch

script = argv
name = str(script[0])

cmd = 'start payload.txt'
os.system(cmd)
if not os.path.exists('C:\pythonspawn\clone'):
    os.mkdir('C:\pythonspawn\clone')
os.system(r"copy payload.txt C:\pythonspawn\clone")
os.system(r"copy " + name + " C:\pythonspawn\clone")

desktop = winshell.desktop()
path = os.path.join("C:\pythonspawn\\", "Internet Explorer.lnk")
target = r"C:\pythonspawn\clone\file.py"
wDir = r"C:\pythonspawn\clone"
icon = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

shell = Dispatch('Wscript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

and this is the batch file:

```
file.py %*
```

Comment: This is the batch file, in case there is something I've done wrong on that end:

file.py %*

Comment: print the name variable and see what you get in each case (running via batch vs running it directly)

Comment: when run from cmd it puts: file.py

when through the .bat file: c:\...\file.py

Comment: I just remember I did something similar a while ago and that argv change when running a bat.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you can let me know what you had to do then possibly, and please!!

Comment: I couldn't make it work, what i did is build an exe with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage)

Comment: Ok I will try that out